# Imported PNG file not working on Texture Paint Model

Tags: modeling, import

I've been working on a low-poly model but as I went to the texturing part of it, I exported the file to draw on the texture, but the import won't show up on the model. Once I get into other tabs like UV Editing the imported image reverts back to the OG texture layout. Is there a solution to this?
[image]

Comment: Can you share the file? (Please pack the textures (File > External Data> Pack Resources))

Comment: @Akshay2005 I can, sorry, I'm a new person towards this site and blender. Do you know how I can share it to you 

Comment: To pack files just follow the above brackets. As for sharing the blend file use blend exchange. Search it up on google. Not too complicated.

Comment: You can share your Blend file via https://blend-exchange.com/ following the instructions on that page to copy the link there into your question.

Comment: @Akshay2005 https://blend-exchange.com/b/ogZog0NW/ I apologize for the wait.

Comment: You did not pack the image texture. The image texture file is stored outside of blender. So when you share the file you won't be able to share the image texture along with it(Unless you share them both in a folder or something like that). But there is an easy optiion. In the top menubar in blender, go to file>External data> Pack resources. This will store the image files inside blender. (Remember this, coz if you ever share stuff to a renderfarm or share the file in general, this is something that you are going to need to do)